# C# WinForms problem with draw image

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

class OriginalImage: Form
    {
        private Image image;
        private PictureBox pb;

```
    public OriginalImage()
    {
        pb = new PictureBox {SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage};
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        Controls.Add(pb);

        image = Image.FromFile(@"Image/original.jpg");

        this.Width = image.Width;
        this.Height = image.Height;

        this.Text = "Original image";
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
    }

    public virtual void Drawer(object source, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(image,0,0);
    }
```

I call this create object OriginalImage in other form on button click, but image is not draw? Where is problem?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var oi = new OriginalImage();
        oi.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why there you are implementing from Form? and not just creating an image and adding it to current form?

Comment: It sounds like he wants to show the image...in a new form.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a `PictureBox` and adding it to your controls, but you never actually use it (you're drawing the image manually in the `Paint` event). Why? This control is likely obscuring the drawing area of the form, as any controls go on top of whatever you draw in the `Paint` event.

In addition, you're getting the `Graphics` object by calling `CreateGraphics` on the `PictureBox` rather than the `Form` itself. This is wrong, as the `PictureBox`'s Paint event will fire *after* this code, erasing whatever you draw.

I would recommend changing your `OriginalForm` code to the following:

```
class OriginalImage: Form
{
    private Image image;
    private PictureBox pb;

    public OriginalImage()
    {
        pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // this will make the PictureBox occupy the
                                  // whole form

        Controls.Add(pb);

        image = Image.FromFile(@"Image/original.jpg");

        this.ClientSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height); // this allows you to
                                                               // size the form while
                                                               // accounting for the
                                                               // border

        this.Text = "Original image";

        pb.Image = image; // use this instead of drawing it yourself.
    }
}
```